# SQL Server: compare date to string with no leading zeros

Tags: t-sql

it's the old DateTime conversion black hole:

```
tbl_a.dob (varchar) = "1/1/1980"
tbl_b.dob (datetime) = 01/01/1980 00:00:00
```

this does NOT work:

```
select * 
from tbl_a, tbl_b
where tbl_a.dob = convert(varchar, dob, 101)
```

because style 101 adds leasing zeroes to the datetime! "01/01/1980"

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You're converting the datetime to a varchar and then doing a string comparison. The better way would be to convert the string to a datetime and then compare two datetime values. Compare apples to apples instead of comparing apples to pears that were converted from oranges.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to go the opposite direction, converting the varchar to a datetime.

```
select *
    from tbl_a a
        inner join tbl_b b
            on cast(a.dob as datetime) = b.dob
```